# CARTODB Torque Map

Tags: maps, cartodb

I have created a time series map in cartoDB. Is there any way to have the units display in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm? Currently the animation map only displays the mm/dd/yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean date in the timeline widget? I'm afraid this text or format of it cannot be changed, you'd need to create own custom time controller.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.. Well I am familiar with HTML, but very basic. In this link this is what I'm trying to achieve, but with my data: http://bl.ocks.org/iriberri/df90d4d4662202894d65  I have a CSV file, but I don't know how to incorporate it into the HTML you see in the link. Would you have any tips or ideas?

Comment: With special HTML/JS much more can be done, probably also this. But I'm afraid exactly same code would not work now, some libraries used there (cartodb.js, visualisations) are changed too much. It would require more special coding here.